# I installed fitnesse-editor for Eclipse but it is not working at all

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

windows->preferences
no fitnesse Configurations
right click not fitnesse option as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons for such an error.

Try starting Eclipse with -clean parameter. Then look in your logs, usually at workspace/.metadata/.log. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

If all else fails, try re-installing Eclipse into a new folder. Simply rename the old Eclipse folder to keep it for a backup.